# PDO cannot connect remote mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

server A(192.168.1.3)

mysql server(5.6.12) port 6603,socket /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock

php(5.5.0) php.ini pdo_mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock

server B(192.168.1.4)

mysql server(5.5.11) port 3306,socket /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock

In server A is work when use

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=DB_TEST','username','password');
```

but cannot connect to server B when use

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:hostname=192.168.1.4;dbname=DB_TEST;port=3306','username','password');
```

> ERROR:SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

but work on

```
$conn = mysql_connect('192.168.1.4:3306', 'username', 'password');
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:hostname=192.168.1.4;dbname=DB_TEST;port=3306','username','password');
```

should be

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.1.4;dbname=DB_TEST;port=3306','username','password');
```

`hostname` is invalid for `dsn` and so `PDO` is ignoring host and using default, which is `localhost`

Answer (score 12):

ok i had the same problem too. the solutions is the space between

`mysql: host` --> this work very well!!!

this way you can connect to remote mysql

Comment: Don't know why you were downvoted. This worked perfectly for me. Thanks.

Comment: This solved my problem and honestly, the major issue is the space in the connection string                                                                               $conn = mysql_connect('192.168.1.4:3306', <-->'username', <---> 'password');

Answer (score 3):

The problem on remote PDO mysql conex are on the db string. The correct statement is:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.1.4:3306;dbname=DB_TEST','username','password');
```