# Symfony docker container can't connect to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker

My stack is quite common, one container for my Symfony app, another one for Mysql.
For some reason, Symfony can't connect to Mysql container with following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

A simple php file to test the MySQL connection, on the Symfony container works with this

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=database;dbname=mysite', 'mysite', 'password');
```

Here is my Symfony parameters file:

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: database
database_port: 3306
database_name: mysite
database_user: mysite
database_password: password
```

And here is my docker-compose file :

```
site:
  build: webapp
  ports :
     - "80:80"
  volumes:
     - /home/myuser/dev/mysite:/var/www/html/
  links:
     - database

database:
  image: mysql:5.5
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"  
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=mysite
    - MYSQL_USER=mysite
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

I also tried with a fresh Symfony project without error.

Comment: Double check config/param files for both environments. It seems to ignore your parameters (trying to connect locally)

Comment: I don't think so, as the error message contains login parameters and it's updated as I change my parameters file.
 PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=my...', 'mysite', 'password')

Comment: I found this answer, that suggests to put a space between `mysql:` and `host`; http://stackoverflow.com/a/25432156/1811501

Comment: I already have a space between them.

Comment: Ok I found my mistake, my session handler config was bad. Dear Stackoverflow gurus, should I edit my question or answer it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the database driver and port to use. As you didn't use port forwarding, you don't have to specify the port for MySQL. Also, there's a mistake into your driver, it's not just `pdo` but `pdo_mysql` ([documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#driver)).

```
database_host: database
database_name: mysite
database_user: mysite
database_password: password
```

Also, why do you specify a `database_path` ? MySQL doesn't need because you call it by TCP/IP. Old SQLite database ?

You could also checkout your `config.yml` file :

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: I included a typo on my driver here,  but my actual parameters file is fine.
I tried removing driver and port, but still the same, message. I will try a fresh Symfony project when I have more tiime.